# What JVM languages use smap?

Tags: java

[JSR-045](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/review/jsr045/) defines SMAP, which helps debuggers support languages that compile to intermediate Java.

The most common use of SMAP is for JSP files.

What other languages/technologies use SMAP?

Comment: Parser generators like antlr could make use of it (not sure if they do).

Comment: There is an opinion that JRuby does. (see http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/08/jruby-java-integration-jsr45-dbg)